# deploying Go binary on S3

Tags: amazon-s3, go

[This](http://open.blogs.nytimes.com/2014/07/10/emr-streaming-in-go/) recent NYTimes article about using Go lang describes deployment as a simple process of putting a binary on S3.

```
Since programs compile down to a single binary, we can include all the third-party libraries we want and deployment is just a matter of putting our binary on S3, no bootstrap actions required.
```

What type of environment would one need to setup on S3 and how would you put a binary on S3 and run it? Is someone able to fill in the details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

S3 stands for *Simple Storage Service* and that's all it is. It's a place to put files where they can be served on the web with some simple configuration options (for permission/headers etc). It doesn't have the ability to run a compiled binary.

What the author of that article is referring to is that he can share the application (with ops or anyone really) by putting it on S3. The advantage being a greatly simplified deployment process, as it's just a single file (contrast to a ruby/PHP app where you would need to deploy all the individual source files together).

You could substitute S3 in his article with Dropbox/email or any way of sharing files.

The reason he mentions S3 is probably because it forms part of a automated pipeline. e.g.

- Compile/cross-compile Go source code into binaries for all supported platforms
- Upload compiled binaries to S3
- Have all servers pull down the relevant binary and start/restart the process

As someone else mentioned in comments, you could use a deployment automation tool like [fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/) or [capistrano](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano) to automate all of this for you.

**TL;DR** You *can't* run the go binary on S3 (or any code/executables), he means he uses S3 to share the build artifact.

Answer (score 3):

What he means is that S3 is where you store a single binary, and deployment is basically downloading it and running it.

That's how I do it as well :)

Comment: Since asker's asking "what kind of environment" this happens in, note that the NYT article is talking about Elastic MapReduce, Amazon's managed Hadoop cluster for processing large data sets -- see Amazon's developer guide for it at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/emr-what-is-emr.html

Comment: Thanks. If possible can you provide a bit more detail for a newbie (not only me but others). Why would I download a binary from s3 and run it if my intention is to host a site on s3? is these different situations?  Can you also provide some info about the steps you follow  regarding the environment you set up etc. Thanks if you can take more time but otherwise thanks anyways

Comment: yes, my question asked about deployment, and in another answer you provided, you mentioned you use Fabric for deployment. That's the kind of thing I was trying to get at. How do you deploy to S3. Can you describe the steps.

Comment: @Leahcim: you can't run a binary on S3, it's just storage.